# Decimal number list input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, decimal

I want to input also decimal numbers. I have tried with `float`, but it didnt work.

Here is my code that needs to be corrected:

```
a = input()
b = input()
list1 = list(map(int, a.split()))
list2 = list(map(int, b.split()))
garums1 = len(list1)
garums2 = len(list2)
summa=0
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if garums1==garums2:
        summa=list1[i]/list2[i]
        print(round(summa,1), end=" ")
```

code works

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
0.5 0.7 0.8 0.8
```

need also something like this

```
1.23 4.1 51.3 44
2 4.1 4 5
0.6 1.0 12.8 8.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the mapping from `int` to `float`:

```
a = input()
b = input()
list1 = list(map(float, a.split()))
list2 = list(map(float, b.split()))
garums1 = len(list1)
garums2 = len(list2)
summa=0
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if garums1==garums2:
        summa=list1[i]/list2[i]
        print(round(summa,1), end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

For `list1` and `list2`, try:

```
list1 = [float(i) for i in a.split()]
list2 = [float(i) for i in b.split()]
```

Hope this helps